# int value passed to methods with Integer and float arguments

Tags: java, oop

```
class Demo {
    void methoda(Integer a) {
        SOP("integer");
    }
    void methoda(float a) {
        SOP("float");}
}

class test{
    P S V main(String[] args) { 
        Demo a=new Demo();
        a.methoda(3);
    }
}
```

Why is the output of this program "float" and not "Integer"?

Comment: Why do you believe it should be the other way? Just your personal opinion, or did someone teach you wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`3` is of primitive type `int` and JVM first widens it to `float` instead of wrapping it into `Integer`

> Widening in Java method overloading comes into picture when an
>   overloaded method does not find its exact matching signature. In that
>   case, when an exact match isn't found, the JVM uses the method with
>   the smallest argument that is wider than the parameter.
>
> Widening beats boxing because autoboxing feature was added to Java in
>   J2SE 5.0 release. So, Java 5's designers decided that pre-existing
>   code should not break and it should function the way it used to. Since
>   widening capability already existed; therefore, an overloaded method
>   gives preference to widening over boxing.

http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/method-overloading-in-java.php